# Best practice updating and deleting an entity with navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities (SaleInvoice and SaleInvoiceDetail) with one to many relationships. This code I have added is working but I am wondering what is the best practice to update or delete values from this kind of navigation property (in my case  list of SaleInvoiceDetails). What is the best way of doing that?

[Here is Model designer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOyp6.png)

```
 private void bbUpdate_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var saleInvoiceInDb= _dbContext.SaleInvoices.Find(_id);
        if (saleInvoiceInDb == null) return;

        var saleInvoiceDetails = ((IEnumerable) gvSaleInvoiceDetails.DataSource).Cast<SaleInvoiceDetail>().ToList();

        using (var context = new ErpDbContext())
        {
            foreach (var saleInvoiceDetail in saleInvoiceDetails)
            {
               if (saleInvoiceDetail.Id != 0)
                {
                    var invoiceDetailInDb = context.SaleInvoiceDetails.Find(saleInvoiceDetail.Id);
                    invoiceDetailInDb = saleInvoiceDetail;
                    invoiceDetailInDb.SaleInvoiceId = saleInvoiceInDb.Id;
                }
                else
                {
                    saleInvoiceDetail.SaleInvoiceId = saleInvoiceInDb.Id;
                    context.SaleInvoiceDetails.Add(saleInvoiceDetail);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        saleInvoiceInDb.CompleteDateTime = DateTime.Today;
        saleInvoiceInDb.ContranctCode = "";
        saleInvoiceInDb.DateTimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
        saleInvoiceInDb.DateTimeUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        saleInvoiceInDb.DeliveryDateTime = txtDeliveryDate.DateTime;
        saleInvoiceInDb.DueDateTime = txtDueDateTime.DateTime;
        saleInvoiceInDb.InvoiceDescription = txtDescription.Text;
        saleInvoiceInDb.InvoiceToAdress = txtinvoiceToAdress.Text;
        saleInvoiceInDb.Period = new DateTime(txtPeriod.DateTime.Year, txtPeriod.DateTime.Month, 1);
        saleInvoiceInDb.SaleType = txtSoType.Text;
        saleInvoiceInDb.Status = (byte)txtStatus.ItemIndex;
        saleInvoiceInDb.SupplierId = _supplierId;
        saleInvoiceInDb.SupplierCode = txtSupplierCode.Text;
        saleInvoiceInDb.SupplierInvoiceReference = "";
        saleInvoiceInDb.TransactionDateTime = txtTransactionDate.DateTime;
        saleInvoiceInDb.OrderDate = txtOrderDate.DateTime;
        saleInvoiceInDb.OrderPeriod = new DateTime(txtOrderDate.DateTime.Year, txtOrderDate.DateTime.Month, 1);
        saleInvoiceInDb.UserAdded = clsUserProfile.US_LOGIN;
        saleInvoiceInDb.UserUpdated = clsUserProfile.US_LOGIN;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        Messages.Information("Invoice updated successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: One time, one speaker said, Imagine if you go to a doctor with `cough`. Then, a year later you come back with `fever`. Doctor opens your case, deletes `cough` and adds `fever`. In other words, register your transactions somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need another inner if condition for doing the delete:

```
if (saleInvoiceDetail.Id != 0)
{
    var invoiceDetailInDb = context.SaleInvoiceDetails.Find(saleInvoiceDetail.Id);
    if(invoiceDetailInDb == null) DoDelete();
    else{
         invoiceDetailInDb = saleInvoiceDetail;
         invoiceDetailInDb.SaleInvoiceId = saleInvoiceInDb.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amr Elgarhy for your answer.how do you do this kind of operation in your projects ? is this a best practice?

Comment: @Nurlan I don't think there is a best practice here, it is based on each workflow, so in your case I will do it the same as you did. if it is working, clean code, so it is okay.

Comment: I am confusing a little bit updateing child elements an entity becouse of this I have asked this question .thank you very much

Comment: Don't be confused, if your code works, tested and has no performance issues and clean code  -> these are equal to best practice. you're welcome